# po vs xml for localization for CGI and PHP

Tags: php, xml, cgi, gettext, po

I want to develop a feature for localization in my website. website is developed in CGI(C, C++) and PHP mysql.

If I use po/mo for translation gettext extension is available in both CGI and PHP.

I am concern about processing and overhead on server for translation. 
Is mo loaded on server and each translation need to done on server itself or it loads on client side?

If I am using xml files for translation it loads on client side and helps to find translation for html and JavaScript using ID.

I just want to know which one is best with respect of server overhead and processing and how mo works.
How it uses cache?

Comment: One thing to note on the server vs client side is the encoding. It can be fairly easy to make sure that the encoding is correct on the server side, but then making sure that it's correct when it's received by the client _could_ be an issue (IE?).  
Regarding processing time, I'd argue that it's better to do as much as possible server side. If you decide to send all the locale to the user and have their browser do the work you're asking more of their computer, and of their connection. Doing it server-side (which I think is cached) helps reduce this issue, and helps with cross-browser issues